# Django: How to access a file uploaded from another function?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am totally newbie to Django and Web development, please help me.

I have two functions:

```
def uploadFile(request):
    """
    this function submits an upload request from the page, and store the upload file to the database.
    """

def DoSomething(request):
    """
    this function parse the file uploaded from the function above.
    """
```

I think in the first function, the uploaded file is a local variable, but which will be used in the second function immediately. Both functions bind to a button.

Here comes the problem, how should the file be passed from the first function to the second function?

Thanks for the help in advance, any suggestion or hints are appreciated.

Comment: Your first function says it stores it in the database. Why can't the second function get it from there?

Comment: yes, the file can be fetched from the database. I think this looks a little stupid, maybe there are any other solutions?

Comment: No. And I don't understand why you think this "looks stupid".

Comment: two buttons on the same page, and won't jump to another page. I think there must be some other way to do it.

Comment: Django does not know or care that your buttons are on the same page. They are two competely separate requests. I still don't understand why you don't want to get it from the db.

Comment: I will take your suggestion, this is a good solution, which could solve my problem, thank you so much.  The reason why I don't want to get it from the database, maybe it is because I am so lazy.